# Check string value in salesforce test class

Tags: salesforce, apex

Below is the code for my test class.

```
Opportunity opp = [select Deal_Type__c from opportunity where Id: = <some id>]; 
Case objCase = new Case(); 

objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c = 'Yes';

if(objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c = 'Yes'){ // this if is getting tested 
    opp.Deal_Type__c = 'Standard'; 
}
 else{                                          // else part is getting skipped
     opp.Deal_Type__c = 'Not Standard'; 
}
```

And only first if condition is getting tested and other is skipping which is why the code is not reaching 75% off code coverage.

the field **standard_or_nonstandard__c**  is picklist having two values **Yes** & **No**.

And if the value if Yes, the deal type should be standard, and if No, the deal type is not standard.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting the field objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c to 'Yes' before the condition. This means that there is no way for the field to be equal to 'No' when the condition is evaluated. So the first 'if' block is always entered and the else condition never is. You'll need to remove that line ( objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c = 'Yes';) before the If statement in order for test data to be able to enter the else block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your code to cover 75% code coverage.
you should try this one:

```
 Opportunity opp = [select Deal_Type__c from opportunity where Id: = <some id>]; 
Case objCase = new Case(); 

objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c = 'Yes';

opp.Deal_Type__c = 'Not Standard';
if(objCase.standard_or_nonstandard__c == 'Yes'){ // this if is getting tested 
    opp.Deal_Type__c = 'Standard'; 
}
```

Thanks,
Ajay Dubedi